# I am trying to figure out how to list categories with thumbnails on the homepage of a Magento setup

Tags: magento

I have tried a few different tutorials, but my lack of experience is clearly hindering me.  Could someone explain how to list categories with thumbnails on the homepage of a Magento setup.

Can anyone give me a clear answer? Im running Magento v1.6. Pointing me in the direction of anything that might be helpful would be appreciated.

Comment: how you display homepage? with cms home page or you have create new phtml file?

Comment: I believe I am using CM homepage--is there a better way to do this?

Comment: I found this: http://developersmagento.blogspot.com/2011/07/how-to-display-subcategories-grid-view.html

Answer (score 0):

Try (change category_id to your id)

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" category_id="123"  template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}
```

You could create a new file call homepage_list.phtml and use list.phtml as a template

Read more @ http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/2075/P15/

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_category->getId())->getThumbnail()
```

and use `foreach` loop for taking each category

Answer (score 0):

you can try below link to achieve what you want
http://fishpig.co.uk/blog/display-categories-and-subcategories-in-magento.html